# Activate PHP on Mac Os 10.7.5

Tags: macos, mac, php

Trying to activate PHP. Guides state that web sharing must be turned on but when I go to Apple menu/System Preferences/Sharing and check web sharing, system starts web sharing then immediately restores it to off.

Comment: Tried opening *Disk Utility*, selecting your hard drive, and clicking *Repair Permissions*. Could be that it cannot start the web server due to wrong permissions set somewhere.

Comment: It might help to specify which guides you're referencing. Alternately, is there any output in the file at /var/log/apache2/error_log? Check your config files using a command like `sudo apachectl -t`.